# Where I can learn Cucumber in detail?

Tags: ruby, testing, selenium, rspec, cucumber

I am new on Ruby on Rails testing. I have seen many testing tools, such as Rspec,Cucumber,Seleneium,Watier etc.
but could not detail information about that.

Please give me a link for this.

Answer (score 4):

Although it's already a bit behind schedule, Pragmatic Publishing has [The RSpec Book: Behaviour Driven Development with RSpec, Cucumber, and Friends](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/achbd/the-rspec-book) due out in September (you can buy a pre-release pdf version now, if you prefer).

PeepCode also sells four different screencasts on Rspec and Cucumber:

- http://peepcode.com/products/cucumber
- http://peepcode.com/products/rspec-basics
- http://peepcode.com/products/rspec-controllers-and-tools
- http://peepcode.com/products/rspec-mocks-and-models

There are tons of blog posts and tutorials on these subjects, but things get out of date quickly, so it's hard to recommend specifics. The very recent Ruby on Rails Tutorial book uses Rspec in its testing, and it's available in editions for 2.3.8 and 3.0. It's free to read online, or you can pay for a pdf copy.

- http://railstutorial.org/book?version=2.3
- http://railstutorial.org/book (3.0 version)

**Edit April 9, 2012**: There's now an entire book just on Cucumber from Pragmatic Publishing, namely [The Cucumber Book](http://pragprog.com/book/hwcuc/the-cucumber-book). I haven't looked at it, but it is likely to be a good place to start.

Comment: Pragprog also has [Rails Test Prescriptions][1] in beta, with the eBook available now and paper later.  It's mostly done--the chapters on rspec and cucumber are there, as is most of the rest of the book.
[1]: http://pragprog.com/titles/nrtest/rails-test-prescriptions

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know about Cucumber, you can start from these websites:

- http://cukes.info/
- http://wiki.github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/tutorials-and-related-blog-posts
- http://wiki.github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/ruby-on-rails
- http://www.themomorohoax.com/2009/04/22/8-tips-for-testing-rails-apps-with-cucumber
- http://blog.flame.org/2009/11/19/how-i-test-ruby-on-rails-with-rspec-and-cucumber

Those are official website of Cucumber, tutorials and some examples.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.rubyinside.com/cucumber-the-latest-in-ruby-testing-1342.html